# Inserting values into table -> syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, mysql

i'm php begginer and I'm trying to insert data into tables. I'm getting error :

syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

This is my code:

```
   $value = $_POST['IME_KLUBA'];
    $value1 = $_POST['ID_SPORT'];
    $value2 = $_POST['ID_SAVEZ'];


    $stmt = $mysqli->global prepare("INSERT INTO klub(IME_KLUBA, ID_SPORT, ID_SAVEZ) VALUES ('$value', '$value1', '$value2')");
    $stmt->bind_param('sssdi',$_POST['IME_KLUBA'],$_POST['ID_SPORT'],$_POST['ID_SAVEZ']);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->close();
```

Comment: what is that `global` in there?

Comment: so much for prepared statements

Comment: When i remove globan which stand in front of prepare i'm getting error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Comment: You should definitely revisit the documentation about prepared statements! You should also add the code, where you define `$mysqli`. Your error basically says, that you did not establish a connection yet.

Comment: $con=mysqli_connect("dudu-news.eu","news_user","bbb","news_lss");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} It's my connection code if u thought about that.

Comment: Then why are you jumping between procedural code and object oriented? Either use the object constructor for connection or `mysqli_prepare()` etc for query execution.

Comment: @lluka Have you tried Ghost's answer yet?

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't provide the instance of the mysqli connection and its not found in the question, just make sure you have:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');
```

Thats the whole point of using prepared statements, you bind those inputs, you don't directly inject them in your query statement

```
$value = $_POST['IME_KLUBA'];
$value1 = $_POST['ID_SPORT'];
$value2 = $_POST['ID_SAVEZ'];

// use placeholders in your query statement, don't directly inject your inputs
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO klub(IME_KLUBA, ID_SPORT, ID_SAVEZ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

// the number of types that you have given must correspond on how many inputs you are going to bind
$stmt->bind_param('sss',$value, $value1, $value2);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
```

I urge you to read the manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Haha great answer Ghost! Was just thinking wtf when I saw that code block!

Comment: I agree with the above "wtf", plus I'll top that "wtf" with this "wtf" => `$mysqli->global prepare`. OP's already asked a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/27349532/ which was put on hold. So, how about another great big "WTF"! @Darren

Comment: @Darren well at least here's something new, besides the never ending `don't use mysql_ functions, use prepared statements` haha.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Haha it just has to be that kind of week doesn't it! It just needs to be topped off with a `"I run this mysqli query and it does't work. Whats wrong with it? *dumps code in question*"`

Comment: @Ghost A breath of fresh sillyness for the day :D

Comment: @Fred-ii- oh okay, so thats what this is about, another user pounced in the comments about using `mysql_functions`, then after using prepared statements, comes back for another spawn of problems.

Comment: I'm going to scream out another one of those if the OP comes back and says: *"It doesn't work"*. (groan)

Comment: @Ghost I have no idea in what direction the OP's headed. You've posted your answer 15 mins. ago, and still no *green ticky* or feedback from the OP. So, that's another WHY-T-F hasn't it gone green yet (`INSERT great_big_question_mark INTO this...`) - `$this->baffled;` - I'm glad I stayed away from this one. ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- anyway maybe the OP still trying to figuring it out the pieces (being optimistic). lets just hope this is not one of those `it doesn't works` reply haha :D

Comment: @Ghost I'm afraid this one may lead to *nowhere land*. A place I once visited and had a hard time finding my way back from ;) I've left the OP a few comments; the ball is now in the OP's court; *batter up!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was telling you about questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370083/php-not-working-with-multiple-errors)...*called itttttt*

Comment: @Darren Yeah; I saw that one and TBH, I don't have a pole long enough to use and to stay away from.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Haha I've been sucked in. Noob move :(

Comment: *Gentlemen*, I'm starting to think that this guy's a troll or isn't in the right field. Let's just say I wouldn't even let that guy pick up my garbage at the curb.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah i admit, i a sucker at this also haha :D we'll see if this will spawn another continuation. i think the OP's intent is to get answers piece by piece until the intended project is in its working state.

Comment: @Ghost Or a sheep in wolf's clothing. Seen these before so that's why a **red flag** pops up for me on this one. Well, you've gotten a couple of upvotes, from Darren and I so far which speak for themselves. I just don't like when people *get taken for a ride*, especially when they're Stack friends of mine. It's the *sleuth* in me that sniff's 'em out, and have been batting a rather good average ;)